# Triggering and listening to an event

Tags: matlab, events

I have a class that represent some data and a (short) chain of results  originating from this data. The class has the three properties `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data3`, where `Data2` depends on `Data1` (it is actually a filtered version of it) and `Data3` depends on `Data2`.

My idea was to trigger an event when `Data1` changes that computes `Data2`, and then trigger an other event that leads to the computation of `Data3`. However, in the test class below, `Data3` is empty after construction.

Note that I use `uiw.event.EventData` from the [Widget toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66235-widgets-toolbox).

```
classdef test < handle
    events
        DataChanged 
    end

    properties
        DataChangedListener event.listener
    end

    properties (AbortSet)
        Data1 (:,:) double = []
        Data2 (:,:) double = []
        Data3 (:,:) double = []
    end


    methods
        function self = test()
            self.DataChangedListener = event.listener(self, 'DataChanged', @self.onDataChanged);
            self.Data1 = peaks(64);
        end

        %% setter

        function set.Data1(self, d)
            self.Data1 = d;
            evt = uiw.event.EventData( ...
                'EventType', 'DataChanged', ...
                'Property', 'Data1', ...
                'Model', self );
            self.notify('DataChanged', evt);
        end
        function set.Data2(self, d)
            self.Data2 = d;
            evt = uiw.event.EventData( ...
                'EventType', 'DataChanged', ...
                'Property', 'Data2', ...
                'Model', self );
            self.notify('DataChanged', evt);
        end
        function set.Data3(self, d)
            self.Data3 = d;
            evt = uiw.event.EventData( ...
                'EventType', 'DataChanged', ...
                'Property', 'Data3', ...
                'Model', self );
            self.notify('DataChanged', evt);
        end

        %% Event callback
        function onDataChanged(self, ~, evt)
            switch evt.Property
                case 'Data1'
                    self.Data2 = self.Data1 + 5;
                case 'Data2'
                    self.Data3 = self.Data2 + 10;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If one debugs this, one sees that `onDataChanged` is never called with the `uiw.event.eventData` with `evt.Property = 'Data2'`.

Das anyone know why and how to trigger the event properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle.

Your code executes the listener callback recursively.
By default recursive listener is disabled.

Refer to [Event and Listener Concepts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html):

> Recursive — Allow listener to trigger the same event that caused execution of the callback.
>   Recursive is false by default. If the callback triggers the event for which it is defined as the callback, the listener cannot execute recursively. Therefore, set Recursive to false if the callback must trigger its own event. Setting the Recursive property to true can create a situation where infinite recursion reaches the recursion limit and triggers an error.

All you need to do is setting `Recursive` property to `true`:

After `self.DataChangedListener = event.listener(self, 'DataChanged', @self.onDataChanged);`

Add: `self.DataChangedListener.Recursive = true;`

Comment: Brilliant! But the docs have an error here, haven't they: _Therefore, set Recursive to false if the callback must trigger its own event._ "false" should be "true", shouldn't it?

Comment: I think the docs describes the situation when you must prevent the case of infinite recursion.